# Java Swing: Jtable ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, swing, exception, jtable

I *sometimes* get this exception. I dont really know where's problem, i use my implementation of abstracttablemodel. I CANT found the excact place where exception occurs, beacause when i use debugger and run step by step exception doesnt occur.

```
Exception occurred during event dispatching:
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 2
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:427)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:277)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintGrid(BasicTableUI.java:1931)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1767)
    at com.alee.laf.table.WebTableUI.paint(WebTableUI.java:52)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:143)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:752)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:747)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5124)
    at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:278)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1225)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5072)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4882)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:786)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:714)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:694)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:41)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1636)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:178)
    at java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:1046)
    at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Dialog.java:1098)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1096)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1584)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1536)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:842)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:986)
    at ui.MainFrame.queryButtonActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:936)
    at ui.MainFrame.access$700(MainFrame.java:89)
    at ui.MainFrame$9.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:538)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6288)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6053)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

my table model:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package util;

import entity3.Document;
import entity3.Msg;
import entity3.Senderreceiver;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author work
 */
public class IncomingMailTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
    public String[] getColumnNames() {
        return columnNames;
    }

    public void setColumnNames(String[] columnNames) {
        this.columnNames = columnNames;
    }
    private String[] columnNames = {"Дата",
        "Тема",
        "Відправник",
        "Статус"};

    private List<Document> documents;

    public IncomingMailTableModel(List<Document> documents) {
        this.documents = documents;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return documents.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Document getObjectAtRow(int row) {     
        return documents.get(row);  
    }
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return String.class;
            case 1:
                return String.class; 
            case 2:
                return String.class;
            case 3:
                return String.class;

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        String toReturn = "";
        Document document = documents.get(row);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Msg msg =document.getMsg();
        ArrayList<Senderreceiver> senderReceivers = new ArrayList<Senderreceiver>(msg.getSenderreceivers());
        //ArrayList<Document> docs = new ArrayList<Document>(document.getMsg().getDocuments());
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                if (document.getMsg().getReceivingDate() != null) 
                    toReturn = format.format(document.getMsg().getReceivingDate());

                break;
            case 1:
                toReturn = document.getTitle();

                break;

            case 2:
                for (Object o : senderReceivers) {
                    Senderreceiver senderReceiver = (Senderreceiver) o;
                    if (senderReceiver.getRole()==0) {
                        toReturn = senderReceiver.getOrganization().getShortName();
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (document.getMsg().getIsRead()!=null)
                if(document.getMsg().getIsRead()) toReturn = "Прочитано";
                else toReturn="Непрочитано";
                break;
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide some code where you getting this exception ?

Comment: Are you adding / removing columns in your table from another thread?

Comment: i added code for my tablemodel. thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can occurr if you are modifying the `TableModel` (or the data structure that the TableModel "sits on") from a thread other than the Event Dispatch thread.

Another common cause of this error is mixing up view and model indices.  For example, if you retrieve the selected row from a `JTable` using `getSelectedRow()` the value returned is a **view-based index**.  If you wish to index into the corresponding `TableModel` you need to convert this value using [`convertRowIndexToModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29).

For the latter case you can try and replicate this exception by sorting the table on different columns and then clicking various rows (in particular first and last), or performing whatever action is required in your UI in order to "process" that row.

Comment: thanks for answer. I dont sort table so model and view indexes cant be mixed up, right? So I think its the first case. How do i fix this issue? By calling  'SwingUtilities.invokeLater'? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's right.  You could always assert SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() in places where you update your model / UI .

Comment: I think i got rid of this problem. Thank you very much for your help, Adamski! you rock!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your `public int getRowCount()` returns the `size()` of your vector.

Comment: thanks for answer. it does return size() of List that is delagated to table model