# SwingWorker + JTable: how to change the code so that there was no error?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, swingworker

I use this code and get errors *java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException* . I know that the problem is **multi-threading and EDT**. I read about using the method **publish()**, but I do not know how to use it and I do not know how to change your code to correct errors. Please tell me how to change the code to avoid any mistakes. Thank U!
**Error message:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI.getHeaderHeight(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI.createHeaderSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.ViewportLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Main Class:**

```
import java.sql.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;  
public class DatabaseTable extends JFrame { 
    private  String 
    dsn = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDB", 
    uid = "root", 
    pwd = "root"; 

    private static int start = 0, count = 10;

    private JProgressBar progressBar = null;
    private JButton btnNewButton = null;
    private DatabaseTableModel dbm = null;
    private Statement st = null;

    Connection connections() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Connection conn = null; 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dsn, uid, pwd);          
        return conn;
    }

    public DatabaseTable(){
        dbm = new DatabaseTableModel(false); 
        JTable table = new JTable(dbm);
        try { 

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Next record"); 
            frame.setSize(400, 300); 
            frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table)); 

            btnNewButton = new JButton("Next!");
            btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        Task task = new Task();             
                        task.execute();
                    }
                });
                frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                progressBar = new JProgressBar();
                frame.getContentPane().add(progressBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.show(); 


            } catch (Exception ex) { 
                System.out.println("DatabaseTable().Exception");
            } 
    }

    class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {     
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            btnNewButton.setEnabled(false);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));

            try {
                st = connections().createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from testTable LIMIT "+start+","+count); 
                start += 10;
                dbm.setDataSource(rs); 
                rs.close(); 
                connections().close();
                }catch (ClassNotFoundException  e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("Task.ClassNotFoundException");
                }catch ( SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println("Task.SQLException");
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("Task.Exception");
                } 
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public void done(){
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            progressBar.setValue(100);
            btnNewButton.setEnabled(true);
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        new DatabaseTable();
    }
}
```

**Class TableModel:**

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import javax.swing.table.*; 
import java.sql.*; 
import java.util.*; 
public class DatabaseTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private ArrayList columnNames = new ArrayList(); 
    private ArrayList columnTypes = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

    public DatabaseTableModel(boolean editable) { 
        this.editable = editable; 
    } 
    private boolean editable; 

    public int getRowCount() { 
    synchronized (data) { 
        return data.size(); 
    } 
    } 
    public int getColumnCount() { 
        return columnNames.size(); 
    } 
    public Class getColumnClass(int column) { 
        return (Class)columnTypes.get(column); 
    } 
    public String getColumnName(int column) { 
        return (String)columnNames.get(column); 
    } 
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) { 
    synchronized (data) { 
        return ((ArrayList)data.get(row)).get(column); 
    } 
    } 
    public boolean isEditable(int row, int column) { 
        return editable; 
    } 
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column){ 
        synchronized (data) { 
            ((ArrayList)data.get(row)).set(column, value); 
        } 
    } 
    public void setDataSource(ResultSet rs) throws Exception { 
        data.clear(); 
        columnNames.clear(); 
        columnTypes.clear(); 

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData(); 
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount(); 
        for ( int i=0; i<columnCount; i++) { 
            columnNames.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i+1)); 
            Class type = Class.forName(rsmd.getColumnClassName(i+1)); 
            columnTypes.add(type); 
        } 
        fireTableStructureChanged(); 
        while ( rs.next() ) { 

            ArrayList row = new ArrayList(); 
            for ( int i=0; i<columnCount; i++) { 
                if (columnTypes.get(i) == String.class) 
                    row.add(rs.getString(i+1)); 
                else 
                    row.add(rs.getObject(i+1)); 
            } 
            synchronized (data) { 
                data.add(row); 
                fireTableRowsInserted(data.size()-1, data.size()-1); 
            } 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: This error comes with a stack trace; when asking a question about a stack trace, always post the stack trace (not a summary of the stack trace, but the copy-and-pasted stack trace).  Tell us which line in your code is referenced by the stack trace.  Your question as posted is unattractive to approach; all we have to go on is the error message text and two classes which may or may not contain the error you want us to look for for you.  Show us what you have done, what debugging you've attempted, explain what it is you don't understand.  You're more likely to get help, or at least get it quickly

Comment: Thanks for the tip, added an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the "synchronized" logic in the TableModel. A TableModel should be updated on the Event Dispatch Thread when it has been added to the JTable.

So I would suggest that instead of using:

```
    dbm = new DatabaseTableModel(false); 
    JTable table = new JTable(dbm);
```

You create the TableModel in the SwingWorker. Then in the "done()" method of the SwingWorker you can use:

```
table.setModel( )
```

Code in the "done()" method executes on the Event Dispatch Thread so you can safely reset the model of the table.

Edit:

You create a new TableModel with code like:

```
DatabaseTableModel dbm = new DatabaseTableModel(false); 
dbm.setDataSource(rs);
```

Then you pass the TableModel to the "done()" method so that you can reset the table using the new TableModel.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Simple Background Tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) for an example that passes data from the "doInBackground()" method to the "done()" method by using the "return" statement and the "get()" method.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer!<br/>  But how to create a TableModel in the SwingWorker? Or I do not understand your comment ....

Answer (score 1):

It looks like two threads are accessing the database table model at the same time. Each time the `DatabaseTableModel.setDataSource`
method is called, the `columnNames` and `columnTypes` fields are cleared. From the stack trace I get the impression that
the EDT is laying out the table header and tries to get column data while the database table model is wiped out by another
thread.

In the `SwingWorker` documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), a worker
thread is described where the application can do the time-consuming work without doing GUI-related activities. In your
case, the `doInBackground()` method can query the database and get the data in the right format. The `done()` method could
then update the database table model and notify all listeners (the `JTable` object) of the changes.

Your current `doInBackground()` method does GUI-related work. You could change this by storing the data (and column information)
in separate fields (in the `Task` class). The first three lines can be moved to the btnNewButton action listener, before
the call to `task.execute()`.

Getting the data/columns in the `doInBackground()` method might look a bit like this dummy example:

```
// Dummy data to test without a database.
if (columnNames.size() == 0) {
    columnNames = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
    columnTypes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(String.class, String.class, String.class));
}
data = new ArrayList();
data.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(data.size(), data.size() + 1, data.size() + 2)));
```

This code could be added to the beginning of `done()` method to transfer the data/columns to the database table model
and to notify the listeners:

```
dbm.updateModel(columnNames, columnTypes, data);
System.out.println("Task.done - dbm.getRowCount() = " + dbm.getRowCount());
if (dbm.getRowCount() == 1)
    dbm.fireTableStructureChanged();
dbm.fireTableRowsInserted(dbm.getRowCount() - 1, dbm.getRowCount() - 1);
```

The method to update the database table model could look like this:

```
public void updateModel(ArrayList columnNames, ArrayList columnTypes, ArrayList data) {
    if (columnNames != null && columnTypes != null) {
        this.columnNames = columnNames;
        this.columnTypes = columnTypes;
    }

    this.data = data;
    //this.data.addAll(data);
}
```

This Stack Overflow question & answer deals with a similar problem:
[Java Swing: Jtable ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355445/java-swing-jtable-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! But how to change my code to the problem was solved?

Comment: Not sure whether I understand your comment. You can use the code and ideas in the answer above to change your `DatabaseTable` and `DatabaseTableModel` classes. Is there anything specific with these changes that is causing issues for you? You can modify the code in your question to show what you've tried and describe any problems that you've run into. Good luck!