# IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0>=0 only when using vector.removeAllElements()

Tags: java, swing, vector

i got the following code:

```
    public void tryM(String...Zeilen) {
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    table = new JTable();
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(Zeilen);
    table.setModel(model);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, null);

    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        sql = String.format("SELECT rezepte.id, rezepte.NAME, rezeptkategorien.KATNR, kategorien.BESCHREIBUNG\r\n" + "FROM rezepte inner JOIN rezeptkategorien ON rezeptkategorien.REZEPTID = rezepte.id\r\n" + "inner JOIN kategorien ON kategorien.ID = rezeptkategorien.KATNR\r\n" + "WHERE beschreibung=\"%s\"", textvalue);
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        Array test;
        int i = 0;
        int j =1;
        Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
        while (rs.next()) {

            
            while(j!=Zeilen.length+1) {
                vector.add(rs.getString(j));
                j++;
                System.out.println(vector);
            }               
            model.addRow(vector);
            vector.removeAllElements();
            System.out.println(vector+" test");
            //System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
            i++;
            j=1;

        }

        if (i == 0) {
            amenak = true;
        }

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

I am trying to add a variable amount of variables into the Vector "vector", then add it to the jtable, and clear it again to be filled again, according to my Print statements, the vector gets filled up and cleared perfectly fine. As soon its done and no more rows can be added, i get "IndexOutOfBounds 0>=0"
when vector.removeAllElements() is removed, no error, but the result is not the wanted one.

Any idea why? Where is a index being looked for? Im kind of stumped.

Kind regards

edit error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.base/java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:466)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:661)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2706)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5724)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2190)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2092)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1888)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:797)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1074)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:737)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1083)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:586)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:907)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedImpl(RepaintManager.java:1643)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1618)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1556)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1060)
at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:75)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:112)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:2002)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3928)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:876)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1884)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Kindly provide a [mre] for your issue. Also, I don't see `vector.clear()` being used here?

Comment: 1) Please [edit] and add a [mre] and your Stack Trace to the question. 2) You never call `vector.clear()` atleast not in the snippet you provided. You do call `removeAllElements()` which sets the size of a vector [to 0](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#removeAllElements()). I don't see anything that could throw a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in your snippet.

Comment: I worked on a mre, but then i realized, that you would have to have my database, a xampp sql server running, the login info, the only other way i thought about was creating an example but im not sure how possible and how timely that is for a fake database
could anything else work for you? Im sorry @yur

Comment: Its the vector.removeallelements(), i used both and got them mixed up! @maloomeister

Comment: Ive added the stack trace error thingy @yur usually it shows me which line in my code is wrong, saldy this time it does not. Atleast as far as i can see

Comment: @Leno22ß6 no, for an MRE you don't need to provide a fake database and what not. As you are just simply adding Strings to a `JTable`, you should be able to create some dummy data and try to replicate your problem without all the unnecessary stuff around. That's exactly the purpose, to pinpoint where you are having trouble.

Comment: I think your problem might originate from the fact that you alter your `JTable` outside of the Swing Event Dispatch Thread. But from this snippet, we can't be sure. Make sure to read this: [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355445/java-swing-jtable-arrayindexoutofboundsexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vector.removeAllElements();
```

Don't use the removeAllElements() method. Get rid of that statement.

Each row of the TableModel must be a new instance of the Vector. You can't reuse the same Vector.

```
    Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
    while (rs.next()) {
```

The above code needs to be changed to:

```
    //Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
```

So you have your new instance of the Vector.

Comment: A Hero you are. Its the simple things we forget eh? I knew about the loop variable but it just slipped my mind i suppose, you have my utmost respect kind sir. Have a great week